# Parsing moth-year format to date PHP

Tags: php, date

i store a month-year data as m-Y date format, and my problem is i cant show the data with date M-Y format because strtotime only work if date formated in Y-m.

this is what i've done but not work :
my data : $data->date = '11-2020';

```
date('M-Y',strtotime($data->date)) //result become Jan-1970
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,It may work

```
$convertToDate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data->date));
$expectedOutput=date('M-Y',strtotime($convertToDate));
```